# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send') (Discord.js v13)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i have been trying to make a leaveserver code for my bot, but i always get the error message `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')` I really wanna know why it always says the error messages! Please help me! Thanks!

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const rgx = /^(?:<@!?)?(\d+)>?$/;

var self = this

const OWNER_ID = require("../../config.json").OWNER_ID;
module.exports = {
  name: "leaveserver",
  description: "leavs a server",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    if (!OWNER_ID)
      return message.channel.send("This command is Owner Only")},
      
async run(message, args) {
    const guildId = args[0];
    if (!rgx.test(guildId))
    return message.channel.send("Please Provide a valid server id!")
    const guild = message.client.guild.cache.get(guildId);
    if (!guild) return message.channel.send(message, 0, 'Unable to find server, please check the provided ID');
    await guild.leave();
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Leave Guild')
      .setDescription(`I have successfully left **${guild.name}**.`)
      .setFooter(message.member.displayName,  message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor(message.guild.me.displayHexColor);
    message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
  } 
}
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you change `message.channel.send` to `message.reply`?

Comment: now i got the error `` message.reply is not a function``

Comment: On your `client.on('message'` section, can you post your command execution lines. example would be `cmd.execute(message)`

Comment: where do you mean

Comment: In your main.js bot file you should have a section that looks something like this:
https://pastebin.com/LxsVh8ZF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```js
const {
    MessageEmbed
} = require("discord.js")
const rgx = /^(?:<@!?)?(\d+)>?$/;
const OWNER_ID = require("../../config.json").OWNER_ID;

module.exports = {
    name: "leaveserver",
    description: "leaves a server",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const guildId = args[0];
        const guild = message.client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);

        if (!OWNER_ID) return message.channel.send("This command is Owner Only");

        if (!rgx.test(guildId)) return message.channel.send("Please Provide a valid server id!")
        if (!guild) return message.channel.send(message, 0, 'Unable to find server, please check the provided ID');

        await guild.leave();
        
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Leave Guild')
            .setDescription(`I have successfully left **${guild.name}**.`)
            .setFooter({
                text: message.member.displayName,
                iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL({
                    dynamic: true
                })
            })
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor(message.guild.me.displayHexColor)
        message.channel.send({
            embeds: [embed]
        })
    }
}
```

Removed the duplicated `async run(message, args) {`

Comment: now the error message is `` Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache') ``

Comment: Let me fix that

Comment: was just missing an 's', I have updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

Try to do this:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({intents:
["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]});

client.on("message" , msg => {

   await guild.leave();
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Leave Guild')
      .setDescription(`I have successfully left **${guild.name}**.`)
      .setFooter(msg.member.displayName,  msg.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor(msg.guild.me.displayHexColor);
    msg.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
})
```

Comment: isnt working ):

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Your answer also assumes that guild is defined elsewhere and would have the client leave that defined guild or fail if guild was not defined. The defined guild could potentially be the wrong guild.

Comment: sorry I'm new too coding, I just copy pasted my code that is actually working. My bad. Ill try to improve my awnsers. Thanks for the feedback!